# Insert image into a database

Tags: python, mysql, image

I am trying to insert an image in mysql database with pyqt5. first I used the QFileDialog to select the image from my computer but I cant send it to the database. Please help!!!

```
def save(self):
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "C\\", "Image files(*.jpg *.gif *.png)")
    imagePath = fname[0]
    self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user= "manuel", passwd = "fame007dav", database = "cooperative")
    self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
    if self.mycursor:
        print('connected')

    with open(imagePath, 'rb') as stream:
        blob = stream.read()
        sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES(%s)"
        val = (blob)
        self.mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        self.mydb.commit()
        print('Image saved')
```

Comment: What's the error it gives you? Break down the question as PyQt5 isn't relevant here, just start with the path to the image

Comment: "C:\\" under fname.